# Sending bulk email

Tags: email, scripting, bulk, thunderbird

I have to send emails to approximately 1000 users such that no one gets to knows the email address of another or the fact that I have sent bulk email. How can I write a Thunderbird script or a simple script to perform this action.

Comment: You could send it using BCC but you might hit your email provider's limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mailchimp's free plan (http://www.mailchimp.com/pricing)